# Convert List of lists to data frame where each list within the list are the results from using Sapply + decompose on multiple columns

Tags: r, list, arima, decomposition

this is my first project using a coded environment so may not phrase things accurately. I am building an ARIMA forecast.

I want to forecast for multiple sectors (business areas) at a time. Using help forums I have managed to write code that takes my time series data as input, fits the model, and sends the outputs to CSV. I am happy with this.

My problem is that I would also like capture the results from the decomposition analysis on a sector level.  Currently, when I use a solution I found elsewhere it outputs to CSV in a format that is unusable, where everything is spread by row and the different lists are half in one row and another.

Thanks In advance!

My current solution (probably not super efficient but like I say cobbled together based on forum tips)

### Clean data down to TS

```
NLDemand <- read_excel("TS Demand 2018 + Non London no lockdown.xlsx")
NLDemand <- as_tibble(NLDemand)
NLDemand <- na.omit(NLDemand)
NLDemand <- subset(NLDemand, select = -c(Month,Year))
NLDemand <- subset(NLDemand, select = -c(YearMonth))
```

##this gets the data to a point where each column is has a header of business sector and the time series data underneath it with no categorical columns left E.G:

Sector 1a, sector1b, sector...
500,450,300
450,500,350
...,...,...

### Season capture for all sectors

```
tsData<-sapply(NLDemand, FUN = ts, simplify = FALSE,USE.NAMES = TRUE,start=c(2018,1),frequency=12)
tsData
timeseriescomponents <- sapply(tsData,FUN=decompose,simplify = FALSE, USE.NAMES = TRUE)
timeseriescomponents
```

### this produces a list of lists where each sublist is the decomposed elements of the sector time series.

##Covert all season captures to the same length

```
TSC <- list(timeseriescomponents[1:41])
n.obs <- sapply(TSC, length)
seq.max <- seq_len(max(n.obs))
mat <- t(sapply(TSC, "[", i = seq.max ))
```

##Export to CSV

```
write.csv(mat, "Non london 2018 + S-T componants.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

***What I want as an output would be a table that showed each componant as a a column in a list

[Desired output format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KE0lH.png)

[Current output(sample)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CT1qY.png)

Comment: The `broom` package is often helpful for extracting model fit parameters into a table, but I'm not sure we have enough context here to help more specifically. Can you share the output of `dput(mat)` so we can examine your data structure? If that's too long, can you run it with just two or three sectors and share the same output?

Comment: @JonSpring I have added a picture of the outputs, you can see that all the sector names are in row1 but the line below contains values for both X and Seasonality in row 2 with the rows below being a further jumble of components. Cheers.